# Convert vector from body coordinate system to global coordinate system

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

I am writing an iPhone app that requires for a vector defined in a body fixed frame to be converted to a vector in a global frame. I know the value of a vector with reference to the body fixed frame and I know that this vector is normal to the global xy plane (It is the acceleration due to gravity vector). Given a vector with reference to the body fixed frame, how might I convert this to the global frame?

In other words,

**g** = < x1 , y1 , z1 > with reference to the body fixed frame

**g** = < 0 , 0 , z2 > with reference to the global frame

**v** = < x2 , y2 , z2 > with reference to the body fixed frame

**v** = ??? with reference to the global frame

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what formula to use or point me in the direction of what I need to research. I have done many a google search, but I haven't come across anything useful yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "change of basis."

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information. You need to know how the body moves in the global frame. Just as an example: suppose the body is stationary in the global frame. Then **g** in the global and local frame are identical, and say the velocity of an outside object moving a constant speed along x is **v**=(v,0,0) in both frames. But if the body is falling with a velocity v1, the velocity of the outside object is (v,0,0) in the global frame and (v,0,v1) in the body frame. 
Look up motion in non-inertial frames for the general case. One quick search yielded http://www.dartmouth.edu/~phys44/lectures/Chap_6.pdf